# How can I click on the "Login" button on the iframe ("google-auth-library") using cypress?

Tags: cypress

This is react project with a google login ("google-auth-library": "^6.0.0") with next template:HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="root">
    <section>
        <main>
            <div class="login-form">
                <div class="form-container">
                    <h1>TEST</h1>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <iframe id="gsi_75">
                                #document
                                <!---start document-->
                                <html>
                                <body>
                                    <div id="container">
                                        <div role="button">Login</div>
                                    </div>
                                </body>
                                </html> 
                                <!-- End document-->                                
                            </iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </section>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, I installed :

```
npm install -D cypress-iframe
```

And set config.cy.js:

```
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  chromeWebSecurity: false,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config);
    },
    baseUrl: 'https://localhost:3000'
  }
});
```

But I cannot launch the "Login" button...

test.cy.js:

```
import 'cypress-iframe';
describe("test", async () => {
  it("test", () => {
    //cy.iframe('#gsi_75').find('#container').should('be.visible').click()
    //cy.get('iframe').trigger('mouseover').trigger('mousedown').trigger('mouseup') 
  })
})
```

Also, I try to use a lot of variants, but I also recieve next error:

```
Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: #gsi_75, but never found it.
```

How can I decide this problem and click on the "Login" button?

I added next code in the command.cy.js:

```
export function getIframe(selector, string) { //(selector: string)
  return             
 cy.get(selector).its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty').then(cy.wrap);
};
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', getIframe);

export function invokeLogin() {
  return cy.getIframe('.login').should('be.visible').click();
}
Cypress.Commands.add('invokeLogin', invokeLogin);
```

When I use cy.invokeLogin(); command, than I get error:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

In commands directory:

```js
export function getIframe (selector: string) {
  return cy.get(selector).its('0.contentDocument.body').should('not.be.empty').then(cy.wrap);
};
Cypress.Commands.add('getIframe', getIframe);

export function invokeLogin () {
  return cy.getIframe('.login').should('be.visible').click();
}
Cypress.Commands.add('invokeLogin', invokeLogin);
```

Then provide cypress command cy.invokeLogin();

Keep in mind that chromeWebSecurity have to be set to false.

Comment: Which selector value should I set except for "string"?

Comment: Its typescript so if you write tests in JS jus ommit this.

Comment: I added your code and error, after that, in the question description

Comment: 'selector' is a parameter that allows to assign an argument, in this case argument = selector. So if you call the cy.getIframe(), you have to pass the proper argument / selector, becouse cy.getIframe works as cy.get().

Comment: In this case cy.getIframe('[role="button"]')